# Executing PHP from crontab

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, cron

I am utilizing crontab to execute a PHP file as follows:

```
0 4 * * * /opt/lampstack/php/bin/php /opt/lampstack/apache2/htdocs/tests/test.php
```

I am pretty sure that the file itself is working properly because if I execute `/opt/lampstack/php/bin/php /opt/lampstack/apache2/htdocs/tests/test.php` in command line I get the expected results.

In the cron log I can see that it is being called at the specified time, but the php file doesn't run (the php code is just one line that writes to a log file).  I thought that maybe it has something to do with user permissions so I tried forcing it to be executed as root (by putting root between the time and /opt/lamp...) but still no luck.

Any words of wisdom?

Kate

Comment: Typically the cron daemon will email any output from running a command.  Find that email and you should have your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to specify the path to the php.ini file with the -c switch and also use the -f switch to indicate the file to be executed.

```
0 4 * * * /opt/lampstack/php/bin/php -c /etc/php.ini -f /opt/lampstack/apache2/htdocs/tests/test.php
```

You might also want to turn on `display_errors` and `error_reporting`

But I also agree with the other responses in that it sounds like an issue with permissions to the log file itself. If you have a global error_log parameter set you can try to echo something out with `error_log()` in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that, when running from Cron, you don't get a login environment. When you run from a command line, you get at least a profile and maybe other profiles run that may set environment and other variables.

You also run as root by default from Cron and you probably need to run as user www or however your web environment is set up.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  The file I'm trying to execute doesn't have a login and does not expect any parameters. It's a simple one liner that writes a date and time to a log file just to verify that it executed.

Comment: Hmm, can you update your question with the script? It still feels like a permissions thing to me. Maybe up the PHP logging output and explicitly add both std & error output redirection to a file. Maybe also move the script from the apache folders to a system on (/etc perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a permissions problem.

What is the path to the file you are trying to write?

What are the permissions on that file and on its directory?

To help you test, change your script to something like this:

```
<?php

$file = '/tmp/logfile.txt';

echo "I'm writing to $file\n";

if (! $fh = fopen($file, 'a')) {
    fwrite(STDERR, "ERROR: cannot write $file");
    exit(1);
}
fwrite($fh, "Stuff to write\n");
fclose($fh);
```

Run that in cron.  It writes to STDOUT so you will get emailed.  It also writes to STDERR if there is a problem creating the file, which will cause even more email.

If this script runs and you get an error, it confirms that the problem is that you cannot write to the file you're trying to write to via cron.

In that event, either write to some other file that cron DOES have access to, or change the permissions on the file to be writable by cron.